# Form Style in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, css, forms, google-chrome

I have [this web](http://tecnifarm.com/contacto.php) with a contact form. Does anybody know how to prevent Chrome from changing de background color of a textarea with the "User agent Stylesheet"?

I have this CSS Stylesheet:

```
input[type=email] {
   border: #e5e4e3 1px solid;
   font-size: 14px;
   padding: 4px;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   margin-left: 0px;
   font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
   color: #586d7a;
   min-width: 491px;
   height: 30px;
}

input[type=text]{
    border:#e5e4e3 1px solid;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    color:#586d7a;
    width:491px;
    height:30px;
}
```

But as soon as you complete the field in Chrome it turns to:

```
input:-webkit-autofill, textarea:-webkit-autofill, select:-webkit-autofill {
   background-color: rgb(250, 255, 189);
   background-image: none;
   color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

I used the Meyer Reset.css but it seems that doesn't stop this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

> input:-webkit-autofill, textarea:-webkit-autofill,
>   select:-webkit-autofill {
>       background-color: #FFF;   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset; }